# Redirect user to after sign up in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying a Ruby on Rails challenge where I have to create a jobs board. I'm using devise to handle accounts, and my User model have a role attribute with 'applicant' and 'employee' as options declared in an Enum. In this challenge, when someone creates an account as employee, I have to check if the company domain already exists (the domain is extracted from the employee email), and if it doesn't, the employee must be redirected to a page for registering the company. Also, the employee become the company's admin (I'm using the admin flag for that). My problem is to make the proper tests and make the redirect to work correctly.

My code so far:

My overridden devise's registrations_controller.rb:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if resource.role == 1
      redirect_to new_company_path
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
   
  # POST /resource
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
      after_sign_up_path_for(@user)
    else
      render :new
    end    
  end
```

In user.rb, I've created methods to extract the domain and test if it already exists:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
         
  enum role: { applicant: 0, employee: 1 }
  
  def get_domain
    @user.email.gsub(/.+@([^.]+).+/, '\1')
  end

  def new_domain?(get_domain)
    Company.all.domain.include?(get_domain)
  end
end
```

And this is my sanitizer on application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
        user_params.permit(:role, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
    end
end
```

However, after registering an employee account, I'm being redirected to the sign in page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you seeing when you debug `after_sign_up_path_for`?

Comment: Are you allowing this role parameter on devise's sanitizer? It is not a default behavior.

Comment: Hello @DaveNewton!
I'm a total newbie on this, but i've tried byebug on a line above the method and got this:
'[160, 169] in /home/rterciotte/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb
   160:         raise ActionNotFound.new("The action '#{action}' could not be found for #{self.class.name}", self, action)
   161:       end
   162: 
   163:       @_response_body = nil
   164: 
=> 165:       process_action(action_name, *args)
   166:     end
   167: 
   168:     # Delegates to the class' ::controller_path
   169:     def controller_path'

Comment: @DR7 I've included my sanitizer on the question. 
Running rails s and trying to register an employee user returned this, however:
'Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"3@bla.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "role"=>"employee"}, "commit"=>"Cadastrar"}
Unpermitted parameters: :password_confirmation, :role

Comment: @Eyeslandic It returns a undefined method `employee?'. Using `resource.employee?` seems to work, but the behavior is the same as `resource.role == 1`